# Float - two digits after comma - how to?

Tags: ruby

I tried to execute a calculation in Ruby. The result I get is 1589.5833333333333. I would like to limitat the numbers of digits after the comma.

The result should always be limited to 2 digits as followed:

1589.58

- Question #1 = how can I set the limitation?
- Question #2 = how can I round up 1589.60 or down 1589.55

Many thanks for help. Language is ruby

Comment: There no commas in sight.  The dot in the numbers you wrote is called a period.

Answer (score 3):

Other option but keeping the object as [Float](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Float.html):

```
n = 1589.5833333333333
m = n.truncate(2) #=> 1589.58
h = n.round(1) #=> 1589.6 # for the last zero you need to format the string
```

And a tricky:

```
k = (n*100).to_i.digits.tap{ |ary| ary.first > 5 ? ary[0] = 5 : ary[0] = 0 }.reverse.join('').to_i/100.0
    #=> 1589.55
```

Comment: using truncate(2) I get an arguement error.

:in `truncate': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
 from immobilienCalc.rb:59:in `<main>'

Comment: @Sunny Which version of Ruby are you using? `ruby -v` in terminal. Truncate with arguments was introduced since 2.4.0: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Float.html#method-i-truncate | http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Float.html#method-i-truncate | In case, update you Ruby or follow the above comments.

Comment: @iGian
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:

```
num = 1589.5833333333333
printf('%.2f', num)
=> 1589.58
```

For question 2 to round up to first digit:

```
num = 1589.5833333333333
printf('%.2f', num.round(1))
=> 1589.60
```

1589.55 is a bit of an arbitrary number, rounding down would usually be calculated as 1589.58. I don't know of any Ruby function that does that off-hand.